# How do I get rid of this blue halo around the close dialog button with jqueryui?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui to create a dialog box, importing [this style sheet](http://gist.github.com/AbeHandler/10433873). It has this annoying halo around the close button. I am having trouble getting rid of it because once I click the halo it goes away (some kind of manipulation from jquery ui) -- so I can't see the relevant css rules. I tried to pick the color from a chrome extension (and then search for it in the css file) but once I click it disappears.

How can I make the halo go away? Going back the the default x is fine.

[image]

Comment: hard to ditermine without html

Comment: Can you create a js fiddle?

Comment: Honestly, the best way to determine what css is causing something to appear like that is to use all the relevant css you can think of that could do something like that and try each way to turn it off. If it's a button element, blue halos show up by default. If else it might just be a border. But I don't see that in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

give this a shot:

```
.ui-button:focus { outline:none !important }
```

Answer (score 3):

That is indeed caused by the `outline` property. Chrome and Internet Explorer appear to automatically add an outline to all focused elements. I didn't find anything with Firefox. Here is how you find out using the Chrome Inspector:

[image]

[image]

If you don't want it to be there all you have to do is target the element with the `:focus` selector and set the `outline:none;`.